# Finite Rotation Groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

One can identify if a given finite group is a subgroup of $ O_n(\mathbb{R}) $ by checking its character table for faithful $ n $ dimensional + type irreps.

Is there any way to figure out which finite subgroups of $ O_n $ are rotation groups (i.e. subgroups of $ SO_n $) just based on character tables or something similar?

Certainly any subgroup of $ O_n $ which is not a subgroup of $ SO_n $ must have an index 2 normal subgroup.

Comment: The character of a representation determines its determinant so you can check the determinant of every faithful $n$-dimensional representation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oh great that's exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for. Do you want to explain how to find the determinant from the character and post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to show that the character $\chi_V$ of a representation $V$ determines its determinant. This is essentially an exercise in symmetric functions. To say it in as low-tech a way as possible, for $g \in G$, if you know all character values $\chi_V(g^k)$ then you know all power sums $\sum \lambda_i^k$ of the eigenvalues of the action $\rho_V(g)$ of $g$ on $V$, which means you know all these eigenvalues (this is the exercise in symmetric functions bit), which means you know the product $\det(\rho_V(g))$ of these eigenvalues. A slick way to package the symmetric function identity we need here is

$$\det(I + \rho_V(g) t) = \exp \left( \sum_{k \ge 1} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{\chi_V(g^k) t^k}{k} \right)$$

and then you can recover $\det(\rho_V(g))$ itself by computing the coefficient of $t^{\dim V}$ on both sides. This identity follows from writing $\det(I + \rho_V(g) t) = \prod_{i=1}^{\dim V} (1 + \lambda_i t)$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, then taking the logarithmic derivative of this product.

The coefficient of $t^k$ on the LHS is the character of the $k^{th}$ exterior power $\Lambda^k(V)$ so this argument shows more generally that the character of a representation determines the characters of its exterior powers. A similar identity gives the characters of the symmetric powers.

Comment: Do you know any more concrete description/ how to apply this to specific cases? For example $ W(F_4) $ the Weyl group of $ F_4 $ is a subgroup of $ O_4(\mathbb{R}) $ . Can I use your method to figure out if $ W(F_4) $ is a subgroup of $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $?

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about that Weyl group or its character table...

Comment: I figured that I might as well ask since sometimes you know everything, but that is a very reasonable reply!